# Moving Protractor tests to async/await (leaving selenium control flow)

Tags: angularjs, selenium, async-await, protractor, end-to-end

I want to move appart from the selenium control flow in my Protractor tests.

Here are the steps and problems I went through so far:

**1. Disable it test by test**

My first idea was to use `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER` in order to move from selenium promises to async/await code.

Unfortunately, I found no way to put one test to `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER=0` while keeping others to `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER=1` in order to do the migration smoothly.

**2. Keep it but use async/await too**

So I thought about a code using async/await while keeping `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER=1`.

Unfortunately it seems not to be compatible: https://github.com/angular/protractor/tree/master/exampleTypescript/asyncAwait

There is nothing about such issue on Selenium side so I am wondering if this is an advice or a real *it always fails*.

**3. Override promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER**

Using `protractor.promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER=false` does not work for me (in beforeEach).

**4. Call the control flow on async code**

`protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute(/* my async code*/);`

For me it seems to mix async/await to control flow...

**What is the right strategy?**

I am wondering, what is the right strategy to move to async/await in Protractor tests?

*I don't want to put everything in async/await in one change but to spread the change in multiple small changes*

Comment: Reading the [full thread here about the deprecate issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969) seems pretty straight forward. You'll need to enable async/await via command line (check Feb, 4th). So, why do you think it's incompatible and what error do you get?

Comment: My problem is that Protractor guide explicitely says "However, you cannot use a mix of async/await and the control flow" and I haven't found any way to move only parts of the tests to async/await and not others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incompatible, because**

Read all about in [this issue here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3037).

As it's very technical, the way I (as relatively untechnical guy) understood it, is that `jasminewd2`, `protractor` and `webDriver` incl. `ControlFlow` are not designed to handle a mix of `native promises` and `managed promises`. It handle only `managed promises` and such are created by many `jasminewd2`-commands. However, `async/await` creates `native promises` and pushes it into the ControlFlow, which ends in a mix of both promises type and it all ends up with heavy timing issues. It can't be resolved as the `ControlFlow` works as expected and as it was designed for. The situation with `async/await` was never part of the `ControlFlow` design.

Switching off the `ControlFlow` to me means, `managed promises` get ignored. But because of `async/await` any `managed promise` would be wrapped inside a `native promise` and therefore it doesn't matter, that `managed promises` get ignored as you keep track of all asynchronous tasks already by tracking `native promises` only.

**How to test both, migrated and not yet migrated test cases**

Create two separate `conf.js` (or whatever your config file is named) and keep them separated. If you have common parts, i.e. `helper` functions, also migrate those and potentially keep the un-migrated as a duplicate as well. (create to .js-files or use a boolean-indicator to execute either or)

@DubZzz found a possible trick to move smoothly to `async / await`. His trick is to convert `helpers` using `async / await` and call them in `protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute`. Then move test by test and finally remove controlFlow execute and flag.

**For Migration these links I can provide:**

[The official introduction and migration guide](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs#step-3-migrate-off-of-the-promise-manager)

[A similar question witha  well documented answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44701633/8683679)

[A good blog about async/await and promises](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8)

[The official thread about deprecate promise Manager](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969). It also contains helpful information in how to make async/await work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, I already had a look to the official migration guide given by selenium. Nonetheless I don't see how it (Option 3: Migrate to async/await) can be applied to Protractor.


I haven't found anyway to set promise.USE_PROMISE_MANAGER to false for some specific tests only.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I indeed misread that.
Why don't you just create a second `conf.js` file, in which you list the `specs` you want to test with disabled Promise Manager? That should by far be the easiest. And you can keep track of which tests you migrated within the config-file itself as well.

Comment: Indeed it would be great. The problem is that those tests are sharing some helpers. Those helpers rely on selenium control flow.

Comment: I think I found a possible trick to move smoothly to async / await but I still don't know what are the real problems behind 'do not mix control flow and javascript promises'. My trick would be to convert helpers using async / await and call them in protractor.promise.controlFlow().execute. Then move test by test and finally remove controlFlow execute and flag.

Comment: It sounds reasonable. As you'll need to migrate the `helpers` function anyway, so I'd assume it needs to be done in any case. About the question why it all is not compatible I suggest [reading this issue here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/3037), though it's highly technical. Highly simplified: `async / await` creates native promises, while protractor/webdriver deals with managed promises. Because `async/await` pushes native promises via `jasminewd2` into `ControlFlow` it gets messy. It was never designed for that.
I edited my answer to match with the results of our comments.

Comment: @DubZzz Thank you for accepting my answer as the correct one. I added your trick to it (with reference to you) to complete the answer now.