# Unable to get the length

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am novice to javascript concepts.
Why i am getting the different output for the same variable **length**?
While it is showing the expected result inside the body ?

```
var length;
element.all(by.className("className")).getText().then(function(items){
    length = items.length;
    console.log("1st output = "+length);//1
    console.log("2nd output = "+items.length);//1
});
console.log("3rd output = "+length);//undefined
```

Output:-
1st output = 1

2nd output = 1

3rd output = undefined

Comment: 3rd is undefined because it's  an asynchronous call.

Comment: `.then` works in asynchronous fashion by the time the code inside `.then` have executed the statement `console.log("3rd output = "+length)` have finished it's execution & at that time `length` is undefined.. You can check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 2):

Because your `all()` is async call so `console.log` will run before you finish `then` chain and assign value to `length`

Answer (score 1):

The `element.all(by.className("className")).getText())` call in your function returns something called a promise- it executes some code, and after this code is executed, it calls the function inside `.then()`.  However, this happens independently of the rest of your program- so it continues to execute the `console.log` after the `.then()` statement.

This leads to what is called a race condition- where the order of operations can be undefined.

Comment: What should i do to fix it .As i want the length of item.

Comment: @shankarDayalupadhyay how do you intend to use the length of the item?  Is there any way you can use it from inside of the synchronous function?

Comment: I want to compare the length of the item,outside.

Answer (score 1):

All before answers already explain what happens and why. So it's clear, that your 3rd `console.log` is executed before your `then()` condition finishes.

What you can try is this:

```
var length;
element.all(by.className("className")).getText().then(function(items){
    length = items.length;
    console.log("1st output = "+length);//1
    console.log("2nd output = "+items.length);//1
});
browser.waitForAngular();  //add this line to let Protractor wait for Async tasks to be resolved first
console.log("3rd output = "+length);
```

However, keeping the 3rd console.log() inside the `then()` statement would be the more proper solution.

Comment: Hi, If my application is not angular can we use browser.waitForAngular() ?

Comment: No, that won't work as `browser.waitForAngular()` resolves on angular-specific objects. I suggest to go with `async / await` as the pure javascript way. Protractor is going to move there within the next 12-18 months anyway. [Read all about here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46660193/8683679)

Comment: @shankarDayalupadhyay : It didn't work or what was the reason for unaccepting the answer? I'd like to improve it, if I may (as it seems you still have an unanswered question).